# depth page Transform on UIView,Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

how to create the depth page Transform animation (Top to bottom, bottom to Top) like this https://youtu.be/c2ccXwwmcnA . I searched in Google but I am not get any idea for how to Implement in `iOS`.

Sample Output Like this:

[image: in depth effect]

Comment: please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717774/depth-page-transform-on-ios/36628668#36628668

Answer (score 11):

I followed the tutorial [Animated Transitions in Swift](http://mathewsanders.com/animated-transitions-in-swift/) and I got this effect:

[image: in depth effect]

## If you don't want to read the whole tutorial, here is basically what you have to do:

#### 1. Create the `TrasitionManager` class

```
//
//  TransitionManager.swift
//  Aleph Retamal
//
//  Created by Aleph Retamal on 4/19/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Aleph Retamal. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class TransitionManager: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate  {

    private var presenting:Bool = true
    var leftSide:Bool = true

    // MARK: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol methods

    // animate a change from one viewcontroller to another
    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        // get reference to our fromView, toView and the container view that we should perform the transition in
        let container = transitionContext.containerView()
        let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)!
        let toView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)!


        let offScreenRight = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(container!.frame.width, 0), CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1))
        let offScreenLeft = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-container!.frame.width, 0)

        // start the toView to the right of the screen
        if !leftSide {
            if self.presenting {
                toView.transform = offScreenRight
            } else {
                toView.transform = offScreenLeft
            }
        } else {
            if self.presenting {
                toView.transform = offScreenLeft
            } else {
                toView.transform = offScreenRight
            }
        }

        // add the both views to our view controller
        container!.addSubview(toView)
        container!.addSubview(fromView)

        // get the duration of the animation
        // DON'T just type '0.5s' -- the reason why won't make sense until the next post
        // but for now it's important to just follow this approach
        let duration = self.transitionDuration(transitionContext)

        // perform the animation!
        // for this example, just slid both fromView and toView to the left at the same time
        // meaning fromView is pushed off the screen and toView slides into view
        // we also use the block animation usingSpringWithDamping for a little bounce
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: { () -> Void in
            if !self.leftSide {
                if self.presenting {
                    fromView.transform = offScreenLeft
                } else {
                    container!.sendSubviewToBack(fromView)
                    fromView.transform = offScreenRight
                }
            } else {
                if self.presenting {
                    fromView.transform = offScreenRight
                    container!.sendSubviewToBack(fromView)
                } else {
                    fromView.transform = offScreenLeft
                }
            }

            toView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
            }) { (finished) -> Void in
                // tell our transitionContext object that we've finished animating
                transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        }

    }

    // return how many seconds the transiton animation will take
    func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
        return 1.0
    }

    // MARK: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate protocol methods

    // return the animataor when presenting a viewcontroller
    // remmeber that an animator (or animation controller) is any object that aheres to the UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol
    func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        self.presenting = true
        return self
    }

    // return the animator used when dismissing from a viewcontroller
    func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        self.presenting = false
        return self
    }

}
```

This is where you set how the views should transform

```
let offScreenRight = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(container!.frame.width, 0), CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1))
let offScreenLeft = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-container!.frame.width, 0)
```

In this case, one view will **Translate** + **Scale** while the other one will only **Translate**

#### 2. Instantiate the `TransitionManager` inside your `ViewController`

```
let transitionManager = TransitionManager()
```

#### 3. Set the transition delegate

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    transitionManager.leftSide = false
    let toViewController = segue.destinationViewController
    toViewController.transitioningDelegate = self.transitionManager
}
```

If you want the view to come from the right, `leftSide = false`

```
transitionManager.leftSide = false
```

That's it!

## Edit:

To achieve this effect:

[image: in depth effect 2]

Here's a git with the project: https://github.com/alaphao/indepth

Use constraints for alignment an sizing:

1. Create 2 views with same width / height of their parent view
2. Align both with `CenterX`
3. Set both distance from bottom = 0 and create an outlet for the constraints
4. Create a `PanGestureRecognizer`
5. Animate the front view bottom constraint accordingly to the pan `translationInView.y`

Comment: Its not related to My Question,I need an animation without navigate the views,Can you please check with the Sample Output.

Comment: the question is related the UIView on swipe with up an down layers

Comment: Oh, sorry for misunderstanding, I will try something here and edit my answer

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik and OP, I tried somethings here and got this effect: http://i.stack.imgur.com/U9kf3.gif that's it?

Comment: Ya,I need like this Can you please update this code,Thanks in Advance

Comment: Thanks a lot,your answer is partially correct, Can you please check this animation once https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/inshorts/id892146527?mt=8 I tried this animation for exact this one

Comment: @ShangariC please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717774/depth-page-transform-on-ios/36628668#36628668

Comment: @alaphao. This kind of effect is possible in tableview or collection view because i want to use custom xibs . Please help me

Comment: @UmaMadhavi I think you could achieve the same thing by [watching the ScrollView content offset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619392-scrollviewdidscroll)

Comment: @alaphao similar to inshorts  app i want to achieve

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution make new swift file and copy this code

```
import UIKit

class UltravisualLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

    private var contentWidth:CGFloat!
    private var contentHeight:CGFloat!
    private var yOffset:CGFloat = 0

    var maxAlpha:CGFloat = 1
    var minAlpha:CGFloat = 0

     //DEFAULT VALUES
    //var widthOffset:CGFloat = 35
    // var heightOffset:CGFloat = 35

    var widthOffset:CGFloat = 100
    var heightOffset:CGFloat = 100
    private var cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    private var itemWidth:CGFloat{
        return (collectionView?.bounds.width)!
    }
    private var itemHeight:CGFloat{
        return (collectionView?.bounds.height)!
    }
    private var collectionViewHeight:CGFloat{
        return (collectionView?.bounds.height)!
    }


    private var numberOfItems:Int{
        return (collectionView?.numberOfItemsInSection(0))!
    }


    private var dragOffset:CGFloat{
        return (collectionView?.bounds.height)!
    }
    private var currentItemIndex:Int{
        return max(0, Int(collectionView!.contentOffset.y / collectionViewHeight))
    }

    var nextItemBecomeCurrentPercentage:CGFloat{
        return (collectionView!.contentOffset.y / (collectionViewHeight)) - CGFloat(currentItemIndex)
    }

    override func prepareLayout() {
        cache.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        yOffset = 0

        for item in 0 ..< numberOfItems{

            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: item, inSection: 0)
            let attribute = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath: indexPath)
            attribute.zIndex = -indexPath.row

            if (indexPath.item == currentItemIndex+1) && (indexPath.item < numberOfItems){

                attribute.alpha = minAlpha + max((maxAlpha-minAlpha) * nextItemBecomeCurrentPercentage, 0)
                let width = itemWidth - widthOffset + (widthOffset * nextItemBecomeCurrentPercentage)
                let height = itemHeight - heightOffset + (heightOffset * nextItemBecomeCurrentPercentage)

                let deltaWidth =  width/itemWidth
                let deltaHeight = height/itemHeight

                attribute.frame = CGRectMake(0, yOffset, itemWidth, itemHeight)
                attribute.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(deltaWidth, deltaHeight)

                attribute.center.y = (collectionView?.center.y)! +  (collectionView?.contentOffset.y)!
                attribute.center.x = (collectionView?.center.x)! + (collectionView?.contentOffset.x)!
                yOffset += collectionViewHeight

            }else{
                attribute.frame = CGRectMake(0, yOffset, itemWidth, itemHeight)
                attribute.center.y = (collectionView?.center.y)! + yOffset
                attribute.center.x = (collectionView?.center.x)!
                yOffset += collectionViewHeight
            }
            cache.append(attribute)
        }
    }

    //Return the size of ContentView
    override func collectionViewContentSize() -> CGSize {
        contentWidth = (collectionView?.bounds.width)!
        contentHeight = CGFloat(numberOfItems) * (collectionView?.bounds.height)!
        return CGSizeMake(contentWidth, contentHeight)
    }

    //Return Attributes  whose frame lies in the Visible Rect
    override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        var layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
        for attribute in cache{
            if CGRectIntersectsRect(attribute.frame, rect){
                layoutAttributes.append(attribute)
            }
        }
        return layoutAttributes
    }


    override func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset(proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        let itemIndex = round(proposedContentOffset.y / (dragOffset))
        let yOffset = itemIndex * (collectionView?.bounds.height)!
        return CGPoint(x: 0, y: yOffset)
    }
    override func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {

        // Logic that calculates the UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes of the item
        // and returns the UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
        return UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath: indexPath)
    }

}
```

In Main.storyboard file use UICollectionView or UICollectionViewController
component select UICollectionView go to attributes inspector and change Layout from Flow to custom and set class attribute to `UltravisualLayout`

here is the project [link](https://github.com/anishparajuli555/IndepthPageTrasform) and this [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/99087/swift-expanding-cells-ios-collection-views) to the tutorial

Hope This might help **GOOD LUCK..**

Comment: can you please suggest me any tutorial where I can learn this?

Comment: @Strange You mean you want to learn Swift or this particular project alone..?

Comment: I know swift, I just want to learn "Custom Collection View Layout"

Comment: @Strange https://www.raywenderlich.com/99087/swift-expanding-cells-ios-collection-views here this link you can refer if you have not been through before else I'll suggest some more link

Comment: @Strange https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementingACustomControl.html

Comment: can't I do this in UITableView? because after implementing the above code collectionView doesn't scroll programmatically.

Comment: Can you please make the UICollectionView scroll to index 3 programmatically after 3 seconds and push the code to your existing repo? Please!!!

Comment: I found it working by changing the contentOffset of the UICollectionView `self.collectionView.contentOffset.y = self.collectionView.bounds.height * 3` Please suggest me if there is any other way to do this.

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale self.collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredHorizontally, animated: true) will help you to scroll to index which ever you want

Comment: ya but it doesn't work with this UICollectionViewLayout