# Tableview page transformation like swiping cards in swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3, uiview, transform, xib

I am working with custom xibs for tableview .My requirement is to use swipable cards . I followed this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35883176/5362916 and achieved some part but i want to show next cell after swiping 1st cell similar to feedly & inshorts app . I want to use tableview because there are two custom cells . Please help me to achieve this using tableview . Is it possible with tableview? otherwise any other .

Comment: what do you meann swipable cards? do you mean that the cells are swipable? and what exactly do you want to happen after you swipe it? that another cell is beneath it? or appears to be beneath it as you swipe it?

Comment: @TPN1994. This is similar to inshorts App. Other cell will be beneath